# Chosen multi-select with Angular 2

Tags: angular, jquery-chosen

I am looking for multi-select option with Chosen library:
https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen

Does this library supports Angular 2?

Comment: if you want to usemulti select Check https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources

Comment: you can use https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/multiselect

Comment: thanks for reply. which version of ng-select supports Angular 2? Looks like ng-select 1.1.0 version supports Angular 5 and above

Comment: check this component https://github.com/SlimenTN/SlarnAutocomplete